# Extraction of information from HTML/PHP web form directly into existing Excel file in .xlsm format

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, xlsm

I'm trying to extract information from a web form directly into an existing .xlsm file. However, I've been unsuccessful in doing so, the file always ends up becoming corrupted. The web form takes two text inputs plus one file upload per user, after which the user may download the uploaded file **with** the given text inputs written into it.

The web form is written in HTML, with minimal JavaScript, and PHP, with the data inputs stored in a MySQL database.

ETA: Code is as follows. Mostly done by the person I am posting this on behalf of. For the download portion, one version of the code used this as reference: https://thisinterestsme.com/php-export-excel/ - however, the data could only be written to a new .xls file.

HTML form

```
<!-- Start My Account  -->
<div class="my-account-box-main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="my-account-page">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                                <div class="account-box">
                                        <div class="service-box">
                                                <div class="service-desc">
                                                        <h4><b>Client Information</b></h4>
                                                        <div id="error"></div>
                                                        <br/>
                                                        <form name="client" method="post" action="php/SignUp.php" onsubmit="return validateInputs()">
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name">
                                                                            <b>Company Name</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="name_1" type="text" required="required" id="name_1" autocomplete="off">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name">
                                                                        <b>Company UEN</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="uen_1" type="text" required="required" id="uen_1" autocomplete="off">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name">
                                                                        <b>Confirm Company Name</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="name_2" type="text" required="required" id="name_2" autocomplete="off">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name">
                                                                        <b>Confirm Company UEN</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="uen_2" type="text" required="required" id="uen_2" autocomplete="off">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <br/>
                                                                <li style="float:center">
                                                                    <input class="btn btn-success" name="Register" type="submit" id="Register" value="Sign Up">
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </form>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                                <div class="account-box">
                                        <div class="service-box">
                                                <div class="service-desc">
                                                        <h4><b>Admin Site (Example For testing)</b></h4>
                                                        <ul>
                                                                <li> <form name="admin" method="post" action="php/Admin.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> </li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left"> <label for="Name" ><b>Admin Name:</b></label> 
                                                                <label display="inline-block"; style="text-align:left"><b>Admin (Example)</b></label></li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left"> <label for="Name" ><b>Admin Role:</b></label> 
                                                                <label display="inline-block"; style="text-align:left"><b>Website Designer (Example)</b></label></li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left"> <label for="Name"><b>Template file selection</b></label> </li>
                                                                <li> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required="required"></li> 
                                                                <!--accept=".xls,.xlsx,.xlsm"-->
                                                                <br>
                                                                <li style="float:center"><input class="btn btn-success" name="Register" type="submit" id="Register" value="Upload"></li>
                                                                <li> </form> </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                                <div class="account-box">
                                        <div class="service-box">
                                                <div class="service-desc">
                                                        <h4><b>Download Link (Example For testing)</b></h4>
                                                        <form name="client" method="post" action="php/Download.php">
                                                            <ul>
                                                                
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="link" >
                                                                        <b>Please enter Company Name and Company EUN for template download: (Example)</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name" >
                                                                        <b>Company Name</b>
                                                                    </label> 
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="Name" type="text" required="required" id="Name" autocomplete="off">
                                                                    <br/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li style="text-align:left">
                                                                    <label for="Name">
                                                                        <b>Company UEN</b>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <input class="form-control" name="UEN" type="text" required="required" id="UEN" autocomplete="off">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <br/> 
                                                                <li style="float:center">
                                                                    <input class="btn btn-success" name="Register" type="submit"  id="Register" value="Download">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <!--<li><a href="Testing.php" style="text-align:center"><b>Super Software - Tax Tool (Example)</b></a> </br></li>-->
                                                                
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </form>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End My Account -->
```

SignUp.php

```
<?php

include_once 'dbs.Connect.php';
$get_pro = "SELECT * FROM users";
$run_pro = mysqli_query($conn,$get_pro);

while ($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)) {
$z = $row_pro['user_ID'];    
}
    
$ID = $z+1;
$name_1 = "";
//$name_2 = "";
$uen_1 = "";
//$uen_2 = "";
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testing');
    
if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $name_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name_1']);
    //$name_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name_2']);
    $uen_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['uen_1']);
    //$uen_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['uen_2']);
    
    $Name = $name_1;
    $UEN = $uen_1;

        $queryResult =  $conn->query("INSERT INTO users(user_ID,user_Name,user_UEN,user_File) VALUES ('$ID','$Name','$UEN',(select File from admin))");
        
        if ($queryResult == TRUE) {
            header('Location:../my-account.html');
        }
}

mysqli_Close($conn)

?>
```

Download.php (successfully downloads the original uploaded file)

```
<?php

include_once 'dbs.Connect.php';

$Name =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Name']);
$UEN = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['UEN']);

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_Name='$Name' AND user_UEN='$UEN'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

session_start();
$_SESSION["Name"] = $row['user_Name'];
$_SESSION["UEN"] = $row['user_UEN'];
    
if( isset($_SESSION['Name']) && isset($_SESSION['UEN'])){
    
    $result = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE ID = '1'";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$result);
    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
    $file = $row['File'];
    $filepath = "../php/" . $file;
        
    // Process download
    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer
        readfile($filepath);
        exit;
    } 
}
else{
    
    echo "<script>
        alert('Please key in the correct company name and company UEN.');
        window.location.href='../my-account.html';
        </script>";
    
}

mysqli_Close($conn)

?>
```

Comment: Without code this is just a journal entry talking about your day. We can't really help. Please add *code for context*.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the feedback. I have since added the code and a little additional info.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. File handling like this is a solved problem.

Comment: When you download this, what do you get? How different is it from the expected file? Is it truncated? Is mangled in any meaningful way if you do a byte-for-byte comparison?